# How to apply proper CSS with GWT components?

Tags: gwt

I have a gwt application which I need to apply custom themes for specific widgets, so I can maintain the Standard gwt CSS (for other widgets that I don't need to apply css to) in the gwt.xml file :

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
```

I am using ClientBundle and CssResource approach in my app. I have applied simple css however I need to make a css that will be able to apply css for: selected and not selected, hover and push events/actions on a widget, just like what the standard gwt css provides.

What to write in the my css file so that for a MenuBar when I apply this:

```
ManuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(false); 
menuBar.setStyleName(AppResources.INSTANCE.css().menuBar())
```

I will get the same MenuBar effects of a standard MenuBar css of gwt?  With the App.css I have below, I just get a black menubar and the font-color of the menubar does not change, I think there is a proper way to apply css with gwt widgets, however I cannot find a good resource about this on the web. What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to change the menubar color theme to say, black, chrome or whatever color but still make the widget look like a real menubar.

App.css:

```
.menuBar {
    background:#3c3b37;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why not try simply with menuBar.setStyleName("menuBar"); I'm sure this will work.

Comment: This won't work if the OP's using a `ClientBundle` for the CSS, because the CSS class name will be obfuscated by the generator.

Comment: @Ashok, perhaps you're right. I just used the plain old setStyleName with the same old CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling you might be experiencing the problem lots of us face when we forget to call [`ensureInjected`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html#ensureInjected%28%29) on the `CssResource`. The CSS never gets added to the page, and so it looks like it's not working.

```
AppResources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();
```